# I want to let user send invitation through their email contact list, Like Twitter

Tags: email

I have been searching for this on internet for some time now but I havent found any results yet. I am not sure what its called or how I can do this. I have a website and I would like to give the user the oppurtunity, just like twitter does, to send invitation to all of thier contact list, through hotmail or gmail or yahoo contact list that they have... does anyone know what its called. let me know if you have any question, The site its Java based

Comment: Why do I get negative point?

Answer (score 0):

may you get help from [this](http://java.net/projects/dalicore), this is a library by using which you can import contact from other account also manage users, groups and permission in your own application  .

Comment: Do you know what is the name of this action, that I am trying to do?

Comment: This is a big concept so i think its not possible to exactly give name to that action.

Answer (score 0):

From yahoo you can use the API see
http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html
You will probably have to use JSON from java see
http://www.json.org/java/
Also see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728421/how-to-import-contact-list-from-yahoo-msn-in-java
There is also socialauth see
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/
This does not work with hotmail presently apparently, just google and yahoo.